High-Frequency Sensor Data Transmission over BLE from ESP32 to Mobile App
I'm working on a project where we need to collect high-frequency sensor data using an ESP32 and send it to a mobile app over Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) protocol GATT . Our target sampling intervals range from 0.5 ms to 10 ms (i.e., 2,000 to 100 samples per second).
Questions:
Feasibility: Is this approach practical given BLE's data rate limitations and the ESP32's processing capabilities?
Optimizations: Any tips on optimizing this method to ensure reliable data transmission and prevent data loss?
Timestamp Accuracy: Can we rely on the ESP32's internal timers for precise timestamping at these sampling rates, or is an external RTC necessary?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
Our Proposed Solution:
High-Frequency Sampling: The ESP32 samples data at the desired rate (0.5 ms to 10 ms), timestamps each data point using its internal timer, and stores them in a buffer.
Buffered Transmission: Every 100 ms, the ESP32 sends the buffered data over BLE to the app.
App Processing: The app receives these packets, extracts individual data points with their
timestamps, and accurately displays them on a flexible time axis.

You didn't say how big (in bytes) each sample is. Nor did you say how many samples you read at each time point. So the data rate can't be calculated.

Is there a problem you're anticipating with your proposed solution? You seem to already understand the problem, and have created what may be a reasonable solution depending on the details Mark mentions. It's pretty straightforward to implement; did you have trouble? Note that the fastest connection interval ever allowed on iPhone is 11.25ms for HID, otherwise it's 15ms, and usually it's no faster than 30ms. So you cannot send packets faster than that in even the most optimum conditions.

Be sure to reference https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1931/_index.html for details on Apple platforms. The ESP32 doesn't have a particularly accurate clock built-in. You would certainly need some kind of external crystal at least (see rtc_clk_32k_enable) or a dedicated RTC.

@MarkSetchell? Thank you for pointing that out . Size of each sample: Each measurement consists of a single data point stored as a 16-bit integer, so each sample is 2 bytes in size.At the highest sampling rate of 0.5 ms (2,000 Hz), the data rate would be:Data rate = 2 bytes × 2,000 samples/second = 4,000 bytes/second

@RobNapier Thank you for the feedback! I believe our approach could work, but I want to ensure we’re not missing anything. I understand that iOS has BLE limitations. My plan is to collect data every 0.5ms, buffer it on the ESP32, and send it over BLE every 100ms. The user will also be able to control and adjust the timing settings.                                 I’m unsure how to improve timing accuracy. What would you suggest in this case? Also, do you know of any resources or articles that explain the principles and functionality of data buffering?

I'm not certain what you mean by principles of data buffering. Generally you maintain a buffer pool (2-3 buffers usually), write into one of them until it's full, and then pass it to the sending system while you write into the other buffer. The only deep principle is "don't allocate or free memory in a tight loop." I'm sure you're missing something; these systems are complicated and extremely situation-dependent and everyone misses something until you start building it to find those things. There's not a lot of general advice to give other than read the vendor docs carefully.

If you add a timestamp to each sample, your data-rates will be higher...

@RobNapier Yes, you're right,  Now I’m wondering if restructuring the buffering system would require significant changes. Do you think this would be a major overhaul, or is it something that can be handled with a few targeted adjustments

That completely depends on your current code. This is likely beyond the scope of a StackOverflow question, since it would require digging into your current code on both ESP32 and mobile. I do consulting on this kind of thing (though my availability right now is quite limited), but I don't know if there's much we can help you with here.
